# Best way to show dynamic content

Tags: wpf

I have a `TreeView` and each time a `TreeItem` is selected I should show a different custom control.
A usercontrol should be created dynamically; no show/hide tricks allowed.

How can this be achieved in WPF?

EDIT:

I'm looking for a general stretegy to approach this kind of problems. Moderators please chill out...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a `ContentControl`.

The `Content` property of `ContentControl` is the data to display.

The `ContentTemplate` or `ContentTemplateSelector` is how to display it.

Bind it to your `TreeView` and you're done.